# Assembler - adding big (128b) numbers (AT&T assembly syntax) - where to store results?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, att

I am trying to add two 128 bits numbers using ATT assembly syntax in linux ubuntu 64b and I am debugging it in gdb so I know that after every loop the result of adding two parts is correct but how to store all 4 results together?? I was considering adding every result to the stack but I can't add the register content to the stack, right? Am I even doing it correctly? I am a real beginner in assembler but I need it for uni :/

```
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
SYSEXIT = 1


number1:
    .long 0x10304008, 0x701100FF, 0x45100020, 0x08570030

number2:
    .long 0xF040500C, 0x00220026, 0x321000CB, 0x04520031


.global _start
_start:

    movl    $4, %edx
    clc
    pushf

_loop:

    dec     %edx
    movl    number1(,%edx,4), %eax
    movl    number2(,%edx,4), %ebx
    popf
    adcl    %ebx, %eax

    cmp $0, %edx
    jne _loop

    popf
    jnc _end
    push $1


_end:
    mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
    mov     $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
    int     $0x80
```

Comment: You've got a `popf` inside the loop, but the `pushf` is outside the loop. That's typically a bad thing. You want to push as many bytes as you pop.

Comment: Why not just allocate another array for the result?